# Simple install script says it is unable to locate package

Tags: shell-script, software-installation, python, raspbian

This install script is giving me the error `Unable to locate package` for most of the programs.

```
#! /bin/bash

apps=(
'python-dev',
'python-pip',
'python-numpy',
'python-scipy',
'python-matplotlib',
'ipython',
'ipython-notebook',
'python-pandas',
'python-sympy',
'python-nose',
'python-picamera',
'openssh-client',
'openssh-server',
'vim'
)

sudo apt-get update

# Loop over apps and install each one with default 'yes' flag
for app in "${apps[@]}"
do
    sudo apt-get install $app -y
done 

# configure ssh
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_confi /etc/ssh/sshd_config.original
sudo chmod a-w /etc/ssh/sshd_config.original

piplist=(
'networkx',
'scikit-image'
)

for app in "${piplist[@]}"
do
    sudo pip install -U $app
done
```

It only installed vim. So I imagine that my repo-list is not updated but I thought that is what 'sudo apt-get update' was for.

When I ran `sudo apt-get install python-dev`, outside the script it did install the package.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting..

Comment: @heemayl Definetly

Comment: Looks like your `$app` gets the comma appended for other package names than `vim`. Try removing the commas from the `apps`

`sudo apt-get install $(echo $app | sed 's/,//g') -y` instead of `sudo apt-get install $app -y`

Comment: `Unable to locate package`..what is the name of the package that is showing in the error message? The answer is in the name..

Comment: @heemayl For every package in the list that was not vim

Comment: @Miline, thank you very much this was the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your $app gets the comma appended for other package names than vim. Try removing the commas from the apps

or 
Try

```
sudo apt-get install $(echo $app | sed 's/,//g') -y
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install $app -y
```

and

```
sudo pip install -U $(echo $app | sed 's/,//g')
```

instead of

```
sudo pip install -U $app
```

Answer (score 0):

Miline's answer that I should replace `sudo apt-get install $app -y` with `sudo apt-get install $(echo $app | sed 's/,//g') -y` was the solution.

Comment: You can also remove the trailing comma `,` from each member of the array..in that case you don't need any modified install command..

Comment: posted my answer :-)

Comment: @Miline Yeah I posted it thinking I could close the question but then I realized I had to wait two days.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the trailing commas (`,`) following each member of the array so that you don't need any additional modification to your `apt-get install` command. So, your script could look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

apps=(
'python-dev'
'python-pip'
'python-numpy'
'python-scipy'
'python-matplotlib'
'ipython'
'ipython-notebook'
'python-pandas'
'python-sympy'
'python-nose'
'python-picamera'
'openssh-client'
'openssh-server'
'vim'
)

sudo apt-get update

# Loop over apps and install each one with default 'yes' flag
for app in "${apps[@]}"
do
    sudo apt-get install $app -y
done
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that the commas were optional this will make the script easier to write